# Is INT the correct datatype for ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm in the process of creating unique customers ID's that is an alternative Id for external use.

In the process of adding a new column "cust_uid" with datatype INT for my unique ID's,

When I do an INSERT into this new column:

```
Insert Into Customers(cust_uid)
Select ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
```

I get a error:

Could not create an acceptable cursor. OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "SHQ2IIS1" returned message "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

I've check all data types on both tables and the only things that has changed is the new column in both tables.

The update is being done on one Big @$$ table...and for reasons above my pay grade, we would like to have new uid's that are different form the one's that we currently have "so users don't know how many accounts we actually have."

- Is INT the correct datatype for `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))` ?

Comment: Per the documentation checksum returns int. But why would you use that to create unique customer ID's?

Comment: We have Uid's for customers already....this only for external use. FYI, the insert is also being done on a legacy server running MS-SQL Server 2000, Running Version 8.00.2039

Comment: Again why would you use that to create unique ID's?  Granted the chance of a collision is low but you also have long IDs.   Why not just 1 - X (an identity column).

Comment: That's not going to work. Hashing Guids will create collisions. Their number depends on the customers number, but you can't call it safe for any vlaue. That's why you have 128 bit GUIDs and then you have 32 bit hash values.

Comment: Assuming you don't care about the possibility of duplicates, the error message doesn't appear to be related to the datatype. Out of curiosity, can you try populating an `INT` variable with the results of `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))` and use that for your insert to see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a moment, forget your issue with what must be an attempt to insert into a linked server (though it is not obvious from your code that `Customers` must either be a synonym or you dumbed the statement down).

Ask yourself: why would you use random numbers for uniqueness? Random and unique may seem like similar concepts, but they're not.

I also see a lack of error handling (again, this may just be that you dumbed down your code to "help" us). Eventually you will get duplicates. You may want to read [this tip](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3055/generating-random-numbers-in-sql-server-without-collisions/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and [this blog post](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/random-collisions). Essentially, as you insert more and more "unique" values, the likelihood that you will get a collision increases. So rather than solve the issue with your solution, I think you should step back and re-consider the problem.

Why are you using random numbers instead of simpler concepts that - at least by default - help assure uniqueness in a much more predictable way, like `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`? Is it to prevent people from guessing the next value, or being able to determine how many values you generate in a time period? If so, then pre-populate a table with a bunch of random values, and pull one off the stack when you need one, [as I described here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/random-collisions). If this isn't the crucial issue, then stop breaking your back and just use an existing methodology for generating unique - and not random - numbers.

Comment: I inherited a codebase that had something like `var tempGuid = random.Next(10000, 1000000)` sprinkled throughout it. There went my weekend. So yes, please stick to unique numbers for unique identifiers.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand...There is something fundamentally wrong with what i'm doing and it just don't make sense.  Question: If I use IDENTITY or SEQUENCE, then ABS(CHECKSUM(cust_id))  should work...cust_id is a IDENTITY column already.

Comment: @Chad I am failing to comprehend what you are using ABS(CHECKSUM()) for.

Comment: The higher ups have a problem with me starting with (1) and this really being used for ASP web development/query string parsing .../index.aspx?clientID=123456789....I'm a strong avicate of [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: @ChadSellers Well start at 1 but XOR the value with a constant when you present it to the user and vice versa. But don't confuse obscure numbers with security.

Comment: Why are you passing IDs in the querystring? Users should never see those, and if they do, they certainly shouldn't be able to learn from them or do anything with them.

Answer (score 1):

Again bad choice for generating a unique ID

But with that said this does not throw an error so I think something else is going on

```
declare @id int 
set @id = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) 
print @id
```

Your update that you don't want users to know how many accounts and custID is an identity should have been in the original problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

> The update is being done on one Big @$$ table...and for reasons above my pay grade, we would like to have new uid's that are different form the one's that we currently have "so users don't know how many accounts we actually have."

Pick a constant and XOR it into the existing identifier to get yourself a somewhat obfuscated number. XOR it again to get the original identifier back.